# « Ils ont étudié »: Est-ce que je dois faire la liaison ?

Tags: grammaire, prononciation, liaisons

Si je veux dire:

> Ils ont étudié.

est-ce que je dois faire la liaison entre « ont » et « étudié ?» Sinon, est-ce qu'il est interdit de faire cette liaison ? Et j'ai la même question pour la liaison entre « Ils » et « ont. »

(j'apprends le français, donc excusez-moi pour les erreurs que j'ai commises)

Comment: You could check this video: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xtplh_les-liaisons-dangereuses_fun?GK_FACEBOOK_OG_HTML5=1 . I'm joking of course, this is a funny sketch based on the pun with "liaison" and the 1782's book "Les Liaisons dangereuses". All the liaisons are wrong in this sketch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalement, il faut faire les deux liaisons

> *Ils-z-ont-t-étudié*

Néanmoins, il est assez fréquent de ne faire que la première

> *Ils-z-ont étudié*

ou de prononcer la seconde très discrètement.

Answer (score 9):

Il y a trois types de liaisons en français, les liaisons obligatoires, les liaisons interdites et les liaisons facultatives.

Dans le groupe verbal la liaison **après les pronoms personnels** *on, en nous, vous, ils et elles*  est **obligatoire** :

> ils‿ ont /ilzɔ̃/

La liaison après ***ont*** est encore notée par beaucoup comme obligatoire, cependant elle fait partie de ces liaisons qui sont en train de disparaître dans le langage courant. Personnellement, dans le langage courant, je ne la fais ni entre *ont* et le participe passé, ni entre *ont* et l'article indéfini, donc je dirais :

> ils‿ont étudié
>   ils‿ont un chat

Je la ferais face à un auditoire, en prononçant un discours par exemple je dirais :

> les physiciens qui ont‿étudié /ɔ̃tetydje/  les règles de la relativité

Pour information cette page sur les liaisons du [Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/liaisons_obligatoires_liaisons_interdites.htm) qui note la liaison après *ont* comme « généralement » obligatoire. La Banque de dépannage linguistique du Québec ne mentionne pas la liaison après *ont* dans les liaisons obligatoires (mais la coutume est peut-être différente au Québec ?). Et le très bon article de Wikipedia sur les liaisons note la liaison « entre les formes des auxiliaires avoir ou être et le participe passé » [comme facultative](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Liaison_facultative) et donne des [considérations sociologiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Cas_particuliers) sur l'observation ou non de certaines liaisons.